# How do I find the config for NPM that is trying to create an errant directory on startup

Tags: npm

I'm new to NPM, but just downloaded it with NodeJS on Windows 10.  I wanted Node JS to default to a path on OneDrive rather than constantly having to go there on the command prompt, so put this into my %PATH% variable.

However, I must have inadvertently changed something in the config of NPM, as now when I type NPM or any valid command (ie NPM init) - I get the following error:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'c:\users\RossCatley\Users\OneDrive - The Orthello Partnership\Website\Sandpit"'
```

It seems its trying to create the directory, and because I put it quotes originally because of the spaces in the directory name, its appearing as an invalid name with an end double quote (but not an opening double quote) when the mkdir is being run.

I've removed it from the PATH variable, uninstalled and reinstalled NPM, restarted the machine, but it still appears.  I've looked for the .NPMRC file, but the only one I can find is empty, so I don't know where NPM is picking up the config to tell it to try to create this directory.

Can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0):

Found it eventually, it was hidden in the .npmrc file in the directory of the project rather than the .npmrc file in /Appdata/roaming/npm.  There is a prefix = "[directory]" directive which was causing the problem.